# What package do install to get access to "psql" client on windows

Tags: installation, sql, postgresql

What package do install to get access to "psql" client on windows xp?  I don't want to install a server, only the command-line client, and maybe pg_dump and co.

I am connecting to Postgresql 8.4 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [download](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgbindownload.do) the Windows binaries (zip-file) and only extract the programs you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [PostgreSQL Installer](http://pginstaller.projects.postgresql.org/) (pginstaller) package and when asked which package to install, unselect everything except *PostgreSQL/User Interfaces/**psql***